# If 'ongoingStatus' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module. Unit testing error

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm facing the issue something like this,
 If 'ongoingStatus' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module. ("contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
                        ][ongoingStatus]="projects ">
     
        Binding to event property 'ongoingStatus' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (goingStatus)=...
        If 'ongoingStatus' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module. ("contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">

Failed: Template parse errors:
Binding to event property 'ongoingStatus' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (goingStatus)=...
If 'ongoingStatus' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module. ("contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
                ][ongoingStatus]="projects ">

**projects.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

import { AllProjectsComponent } from './all-projects.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ProjectsService } from './../../../../services/projects/projects.service';
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';
import { ProjectObject } from './../../../../models/project.model';
import { MockProjectService } from './../../../../mock/mockProject.service';



describe('AllProjectsComponent', () => {
  let component: AllProjectsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AllProjectsComponent>;
  let service : ProjectsService;
  let response;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AllProjectsComponent ],
      imports: [  RouterTestingModule, GooglePlaceModule ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ProjectsService,
          useClass: MockProjectService
        },],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AllProjectsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(ProjectsService);
    response = {

      project: {
          projectType : "public",
          status : "open",
      }    

  } as ProjectObject

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(service.getAllprojects()).toBe(response);
  })
```

**project.component.html**

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
    <app-ongoing-projects [ongoingStatus]="projects "></app-ongoing-projects>
 </div>
```

***project.component.ts***

```
import { ProjectObject } from './../../../../models/project.model';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectsService } from './../../../../services/projects/projects.service';
import { GooglePlaceDirective } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';
import { Address } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete/objects/address';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-projects',
  templateUrl: './all-projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-projects.component.scss']
})
export class AllProjectsComponent implements OnInit {


  // public projects;
  public projects: ProjectObject[];
  @ViewChild('placesRef', { static: false }) placesRef: GooglePlaceDirective;
  public option = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'IN' }
  };

  public location: string;
  public licenseType: string;

  public resetBtn = false;
  public loading = true;

  validdata: boolean;
  constructor( private projectsService: ProjectsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.projectsService.getAllprojects().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.projects = data;
      this.loading = false;

      if (!this.projects['0']) {
       this.validdata = true;

      }
      });

  }

  public handleAddressChange(address: Address) {
    this.location = address.formatted_address;
    console.log(address)
  }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the module of the `app-ongoing-projects` component or to add its class to the `declarations` array of the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

If it's very complicated and you would prefer to mock it - consider usage of `ng-mocks` library, it helps with such cases: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks

Then you could do

```js
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AllProjectsComponent, MockComponent(OngoingProjectsComponent) ],
      imports: [  MockModule(RouterModule), MockModule(GooglePlaceModule) ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ProjectsService,
          useClass: MockProjectService
        },],
    })
    .compileComponents();
```

Comment: I get some issue and your answer help me, thx u a lot)